# Ruby on Rails - show current date only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm creating a small lesson app, with a different lesson for each day. I'm wanting to show the current days lesson only on the index, and can't figure out how. I googled and found some info that came close, but still couldn't fix the problem. I only have one controller, DaysController. No user controller.

For my model(day.rb) I've tried this

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :description, :date, :link_to, :presence => true
  scope :created_on, lambda {|date| {:conditions => ['created_at >= ? AND created_at <= ?', date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day]}}


  def self.today
    self.created_on(Date.today)
  end

end
```

And for my index I've tried these

```
  <% @day.created_on(Date.today) %>

  <% @day.today %>
```

any advice??

Comment: Tell us the error message or incorrect behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly and for simplicity sake is this essentially what you are trying to achieve?

Controller:

```
def index
 @days = Day.all
end
```

View (index.html.erb):

```
<% @days.each do |day| %>
<% if day.created_at == Date.today %>
 <%= day.field_name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: So I just tried that, and the errors went away, but it's still not showing the current lesson

Comment: day is the entire lesson so you will need to do: <%= day.field %> and replace field with the necessary field you want to see

Comment: @TuckerMayo if my answer was the solution you used. Do you mind marking it as the correct answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would change the `scope` to just use the `Date` object and I assume that you want your condition to use the newer syntax:

```
scope :created_on, ->(date) { where(created_at: date) }
```

Then the `Day.today` method should work without any change.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :today, lambda { where('CAST(created_at AS date) = ?', Date.today) }
```

And use it like this:

```
@days = Day.today
# returns a list of `Day` records where the `created_at`'s date is equal to today's date
```